# Windows 7 and Fedora on separate drives

Tags: windows, fedora, dualboot

I have and old 240 gb SATA SSD with Windows 7 installed.

Today my new 1 tb NVME SSD arrived and I decided to use it for Fedora.

I wanted to make the systems as independent as possible, so I physically disconnected my old SSD before installing Fedora on the new one. I expected to see both SSDs in my UEFI's boot priority list and switch them at will.
However when I connected my old SSD back, I couldn't see it in the boot priority list. When I press F11 and choose my old SSD as boot device I get "Reboot and select proper boot device" error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/80XbJ.jpg

The Windows' boot partition (sda1/sda2) is intact:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/siAtR.png

So what went wrong and how can I fix it?

Update: all right, I updated grub and now I can choose Windows (sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2-efi.cfg)
Not what I wanted, but okayish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create separate UEFI boot entry as the old one was overwriten when you removed the disk.

You are going to be using [efibootmgr](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr) to add new entry for you old windows system. It might look like this but depends on your system.

```
efibootmgr -c  -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi" -d /dev/sdb -p 2
```

BTW This will come you handy once windows updates and deletes your linux boot entry, just spin up some LIVE distro and readd the entry.

Comment: Thank you! But before I use it, why "-d  /dev/sdb -p 2"?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/siAtR.png
sdb is my old 1 tb HDD with personal data, without any OS on it.
sda is my old 240 gb SSD with Windows 7.

Comment: As stated "It might look like this but depends on your system." It's just example and you should change it to suit your environment. You should mount the boot partitions and find .EFI file that is being loaded by windows and once you find it out the right disk and partition into the example provided.

Comment: The entry was there, just inactive (no asterisk), so it was even easier https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KoFc.png

Comment: Good for you, you will probably want to change the boot order efibootmgr -o current setting is Fedora everything else and windows last, you will probably want Fedora, Windows and then just rest.

Comment: After reboot I couldn't find the SSD with Windows in the boot priority list. Then after reboot the asterisk was gone. I think I am gonna give up.

Comment: Just try to create it as new entry as I suggested first.